# Trouble with passing a variable at its given iteration

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Imagine there is a list displaying X amount of user profiles with each profile having a 'Contact' button at the bottom of the frame of each profile. If I click the 'Contact' button for a given profile displayed on the list, the name associated with profile with which the button was pressed is given a session variable to be used in the next page, being the contact message.
[image]

The issue I am struggling to troubleshoot is: when the 'Contact' button is pressed for any given profile, the name of the last profile is stored into the session variable. What I need instead,is that when the 'Contact' button of a given profile is pressed, I would like the name corresponding with the profile in question to be stored into the session variable.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($searchST) {
    while ($row = $searchST->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<div class="z">';
      echo  '<div class="x">';
      echo    '<div class="y">';
      echo       '<div class="text_info">';
      echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C1</div><textarea readonly name='c1' id='a' rows='3' cols='54' maxlength='162' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c1"]."</textarea><br />";
      echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C2</div><textarea readonly name='c2' id='a' rows='3' cols='54' maxlength='162' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c2"]."</textarea><br />";
      echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C3</div><textarea readonly name='c3' id='a' rows='15' cols='54' maxlength='810' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c3"]."</textarea><br />";
      echo           "<div id='input_titles'>C4</div><textarea readonly name='c4' id='a' rows='2' cols='54' maxlength='108' onCopy='return false' onDrag='return false' onDrop='return false' onPaste='return false' autocomplete='off'>".$row["c4"]."</textarea>";
      echo       '</div>';
      echo       '<div class="visual_info">';
      echo           '<div class="p_pic_image">';
      echo              "<img src='".$row["pic"]."' id='p_pic'> ";
      echo           '</div>';
      echo           '<div class="country_and_name">';
      echo              "<textarea readonly name='country' id='country' rows='1' cols='14'>".$row["country"]."</textarea>";
      echo              "&nbsp".$row["first_name"];
      echo           '</div>';
      echo       '</div>';
      echo      '<form action="network.php" method="POST">';
      echo         '<input type="submit" name="message" id="message" value="Message">';
      echo      '</form>';
      echo    '</div>';
      echo  '</div>';
      echo '</div>';

  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $carry = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users`";
        $carryST = $con->query($carry);
        if($carryST) {
          while ($row = $carryST->fetch_assoc()) {
              $_SESSION['to_name'] = $row["first_name"];

          }
        }

        $carryST->close();
        header("location: compose.php");
        exit();
      }


      }

    }
      $searchST->close();
  } else {

  }
```

Here is the `compose.php`, where the name is being passed on to :

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once("./inc/connect.inc.php");
  if(!isset($_SESSION["email_login"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
  }
  else {
  }
?>

<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
  ini_set('display_errors','on');
  ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
?>
                     .
             (assume html skeleton)
                     .
 <header>
  <?php echo $_SESSION["to_name"]; ?>
  <div class = "prep_stmt">Ah, I was expecting you, <?php $_SESSION["to_name"]; ?>...</div>
</header>
```

Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what problems you have run into? Can you tell us more about "not responding properly"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I mentioned them in the middle but I will re postion. Thank you for the warm welcome!

Comment: `$_SESSION['to_name']` is never set. Is this correct `$row["first_name"] = $_SESSION['to_name'];` ? I feel like it should be the opposite, no?

Comment: @Berriel You are right, but even then when I submit the post for the second iteration, the `to_name` will display the name of the last iterated `first_name` instead of displaying the respective `first_name` of the second iteration.

Comment: Rather than echoing that much html, you can embed php code inside html.

Comment: @Mr-Kimbles Yes, you're assigning different values to the same variable multiple times within a loop. The value of this variable will always be equal to the last assignment.

Comment: @Samosa If I do that I would have to put `while loops` on every section I want information on, right? I will probably do that as my database grows since by then I can confidently set a fixed limit of available records to fill the html.

Comment: @Berriel Hmm, I thought I could've avoided that if I nested the post form within the while loop (since with each iteration the `first_name` would be included into the interated session variable). How can I go about fixing this? WIll I have to use some `n+1` series or what not?

Comment: @Mr-Kimbles Use `input type="hidden"` with the data you want to pass and assign it to the `session` var you want.

Comment: @Berriel The that bothers me with using that method is that I would have to know the exact contents of user submitted into, which just impossible for me to determine.